# Why isn't O=N-O-O the best lewis structure for NO3-?

Tags: ions, lewis-structure

I'm practicing lewis structures and I'm stuck on the one for NO3 -1 (nitrate ion). I understand that N has to be the central atom because it is the least electronegative, but I'm confused why all the O have to be bonded to the N atom.

With O=N-O-O, you get 3 zero formal charges and one -1 instead of one zero, two -1 and one 1, which seems better. Also, H2O2 is a straight line instead of having the both H and and one of the O around a central O atom, so I'm confused why the nitrate ion must be the opposite.

Here is the work I did:
[image]

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with that. It is just that we _know_  all three O are attached to N.

Comment: And O-O bond is quite unrealistic really. You'll get the hang of the empirical part of Chemistry on studying it a little deeper.

Comment: You win according to the rules you were given and were applying. The "correct answer" wins because that is what we observe in reality. So you discovered an exception to the rules you were given.

Comment: [Peroxynitrite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peroxynitrite) sure does exist. There no such thing as "best" structure. You could ask why it's much more reactive, though.